# Windows Batch Script giving unexpected results when ran on two different servers

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have the below batch script which is giving me unexpected result. When i ran on Server A  its always writing "Yes_Outstanding.txt" file even though my file abc.txt has 0.

But when i ran this on a different windows server B its giving me right result .Not sure what's wrong the server A

```
@echo off

for %%i in (%~dp0abc.txt) do (
findstr /x /c:"0" "%%i"
if errorlevel 1 (type NUL > %~dp0Yes_Outstanding.txt) else (type NUL > %~dp0No_Outstanding.txt)
)
```

Please Help.

Comment: Why are you using the FOR command? There is no need for it in this code.

Comment: may the folder on Server A have a space? Get used to always enclose paths and filenames with quotes. May the file on Server A contain `0<space>` instead fo just `0`?

Comment: What about Windows versions, same on both servers? Windows scripting sometimes differ in its behaviour across OS versions....

Comment: As already mentioned there is no need for the FOR loop. `FINDSTR/LX "0" "%~dp0abc.txt">NUL && (command upon successful match) || (command upon unsuccessful match)` Additionally you are both reading from and writing to the script's location; you will need to be sure that you have write permissions at that location.

Comment: I have removed the for loop and the below script is still not running on Server A 



@echo off

findstr /x /c:"0" "%~dp0abc.txt"
if errorlevel 1 (type NUL > %~dp0Yes_Outstanding.txt) else (type NUL > %~dp0No_Outstanding.txt) ...



I checked Windows versions on A & B servers and they both are same.
No issues with permissions

Above script worked fine on server B.

Comment: I found the root cause. My path variable got messed up .It was missing C:\Windows\System32. Once i added it to the path it started working fine. Thanks for all the suggestions and tips.